# Запятая при сравнительном обороте

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

> После того, как он улыбнулся, девушка сказала: "Ты улыбаешься как босс."

Перед *как* будет запятая или нет? Я подозреваю, что "улыбаешься" может быть глаголом состояния, а не действия. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Этот вопрос имел бы скорый и, главное, обоснованный ответ, если фразу расширить хотя бы одной, предшествующей. Нужно немного конкретики.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**После того как он улыбнулся, девушка сказала: "Ты улыбаешься как босс".**

Скорее всего, это именно сравнительный оборот, но он не обособляется, так как входит в основное содержание предложение: пауза отсутствует, интонационное ударение не ставится на глаголе, но ставится на обороте.

И по семантике речь идет об особой улыбке: уверенной, покровительственной, снисходительной

**Примечание:** В начале предложения составной подчинительный союз обычно не расчленяется.

Comment: То есть, если "ты улыбаешься особым типом улыбки, который характерен для боссов" — тогда запятой нет. А если "твоя улыбка похожа на улыбку нашего босса" — тогда запятая нужна?

Comment: Семантика здесь на втором месте, а на первом месте, как всегда, структура. И вот эта структура не позволяет сделать паузу в таком коротком предложении. Сравнить: Ты улыбаешься, как (улыбается) наш босс. Это уже неполное сравнительное придаточное. Казалось бы, семантика должна  быть всегда первой,  она управляет пунктуацией, и это действительно так, но управление у нас не прямое, а косвенное, через структуру предложения. Если хочешь передать определенный смысл, то правильно составь предложение, чтобы оно читалось однозначно.

Comment: А если "Ты улыбаешься(,) как Иванов". Здесь тоже победит структура?

Comment: Нет, в случае конкретного лица структура так просто не победит (запятую придется поставить и паузу сделать),  смыслу здесь контекст поможет, расскажет,  как этот Иванов улыбается конкретно. Но у структуры  тоже есть помощники - слова "совсем, совершенно, почти, вроде, точь-в-точь, именно, просто, прямо".  Любое подставьте, и вот уже нет запятой. А смысл практически не изменился: Ты улыбаешься точь-в точь как Иванов.

Comment: Тут я с Вами согласен. В хорошо написанном тексте структура и семантика дружат. И такой текст легко читается.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант №1. Улыбка парня напоминала улыбку их босса. Это сравнение, и запятая нужна.

Вариант №2. Босс улыбнулся девушке, но именно как босс, а не как друг. Здесь имеется в виду "в качестве босса". Запятая не нужна.

Вариант №3. Парень улыбался особым типом улыбки, который характерен для боссов.
Улыбался как? Улыбкой босса. Это скорее обстоятельство, чем сравнение. Запятая не нужна.

Примечание. Точка ставится после кавычек:

**А: “П”.**

Answer (score 0):

Ответ добавлен после дискуссии.

**Вариант 1. У них есть общий босс**

(1) **Ты улыбаешься, как наш босс.**  (2) Ты улыбаешься как босс/ты улыбаешься, как босс.

Предложение (1) понимается однозначно, а предложение (2) неясно по смыслу: как наш босс или вообще как босс (= снисходительно, покровительственно).  Это  недостаток предложения, коммуникативная точность нарушена, собеседник может понять вас неправильно.

**Вариант 2. У них нет общего босса**

Предложение имеет однозначный смысл: **Ты улыбаешься как босс** (снисходительно, покровительственно), и мне это не очень нравится.

Comment: А это не будет неполное придаточное сравнительное?

Comment: Это у девушки надо спросить, что она хочет сказать: как мой босс, как наш босс? Тогда так и надо говорить, и это будет неполное сравнительное предложение. А если она имеет в виду качественное значение оборота и говорит "как босс (=снисходительно)", то это будет необособленное обстоятельство.

Comment: Т.е "Ты улыбаешься, как мой босс" уже будет неполным придаточным?

Comment: А если, например, такое предложение: "Он всегда улыбался как босс". Здесь уже сравнительный оборот будет? А, следовательно,запятая нужна. Или я недопонимаю?

Comment: Знаете, в этой теме самое неблагодарное занятие - это самому придумывать предложения (иногда не очень удачной структуры), которые к тому же никак не связаны с конкретной ситуацией. Вы сами должны точно знать, что хотите сказать, и уже потом подбирать такую форму, чтобы читатель/слушатель вас точно понял. Иначе эту тему освоить невозможно, вы постоянно будете ошибаться.

Comment: Смысла здесь два: (1) он улыбается покровительственно,  снисходительно, как босс; (2) его улыбка ЧЕМ-ТО похожа на улыбку нашего (моего) босса. Согласитесь, что смысл совершенно разный. А теперь подбираем однозначную форму. (1)  Ты улыбаешься как босс. - А как улыбаются боссы? - Ну, снисходительно. покровительственно.(2) Ты улыбаешься (так же), как наш босс. Ты улыбаешься совсем как наш босс.  Или: Ты улыбаешься (так же), как мой босс. - А как он улыбается? Вы должны представлять все эти ситуации и диалоги и говорить естественно, как в жизни.